# SQL Server Integration Services Package Deployment Wizard Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis, bids

I am trying to deliver an SSIS package to SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition running on Windows Server 2003 R2 (64bit).

The package itself is quite simple, just a basic read/write of a MySQL table (testing the integration).

I am able to build and deploy the package on my development machine, and I'm able to debug & build the package on the server that will eventually host it (using the local install of BIDS), but for some reason the deployment wizard fails when I attempt to execute the build package from Windows.

The error message that I get is:

```
TITLE: Package Installation Wizard
------------------------------
Unexpected error occurred.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with 
CLSID {E44847F1-FD8C-4251-B5DA-B04BB22E236E} failed due 
to the following error: 80040154. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)
------------------------------
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with 
CLSID {E44847F1-FD8C-4251-B5DA-B04BB22E236E} failed due 
to the following error: 80040154. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)
```

The install seems to have the DLLs in the right place... Has anybody else come across this particular problem? Any tips would be appreciated. I've looked up the error in various places, but cant' seem to find any other cases quite the same as mine.

Many thanks,
Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the install to SQL Server 2005 SP2 solved this issue.